# Как сделать тень для 3d пай-чарта?

Tags: winforms, .net, c#

Пишу на WPF + C#. в .net 4.0 появились чарты для winforms. Разместить winform control на wpf окне не составило труда, но как добавить тень для 3d pie-chart - никак не пойму. Тень ставится, в случае если чарт не 3d. По аналогии сделать не получается :( Кто сталкивался? Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить использование DropShadowEffect, либо перекрытие свойства CreateParams

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

        cp.ClassStyle |= 0x00020000; // CS_DROPSHADOW

        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Делаю что вы просили. Наследую основной чарт. Переписываю свойство. Создаю экземпляр "своего" чарта. Говорю ему быть 3d пирогом. Эффект тот же. DropShadowEffect не нашел.